# Style label in md-optgrp

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material, optgroup

Currently I'm having issues styling the label in md-optgrp.  As of now, the code below is setting `{{groupName}}` as all caps, I tried css but that didn't make the trick.  Any ideas how can I add styling (capitalize, bolds etc) to the label?

```
<md-optgroup label = "{{groupName}}" ng-repeat = "groupName in $ctrl.AllNames">
   <md-option></md-option>
</md-optgroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `text-transform` property in css to convert to lowercase

```
.md-optgroup label {
text-transform: lowercase;
}
```